# Need help optimizing Java program for Goldbach Conjecture

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I need to print all prime numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 and print all even numbers from 4 to 10,000 and two prime numbers that sum to it.

I have a sieve method that changes all non-prime numbers in an array to a 0 (the problem specifically asks for this to be done), and I need to use a goldbach method that passes this array and displays all even numbers from 4 to 10,000 and two primes that sum up to that number.

The point of the goldbach portion of the problem is to print the numbers efficiently, and I am pretty sure my solution uses a polynomial time search when the correct solution is to be done with a linear time search. Any clue on how I might optimize this?

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class sieveAndGoldbach {

    public static void sieve(int[] a)   {
        int n = a.length;
        a[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++)     {

            if (a[i] != 0)  {

                for (int j = a[i]*a[i]; j <= n; j+=a[i])    {
                    a[j-1] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void goldbach(int[] a)    {
        int max = 10000;

        for (int i = 4; i <= max; i += 2)   {
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < i/2; j++) {

                if (a[j] != 0)  {
                    int difference = i-a[j];

                    for (int k = 0; k < max; k++) {

                        if (a[k] == difference && count == 0)   {
                            System.out.println(i + " = " + a[j] + " + " + (difference));
                            count++;
                            }                       
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        //initialize and fill array from 1 to n     
        int n = 1000000;        //initially one million GOLDBACH METHOD WILL NOT WORK FOR n < 10,000
        int[] a = new int[n];       
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = i + 1;
        }       

        //Call sieve method on array a, then print all primes, not the zeros
        sieve(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            if (a[i] != 0)  {
            System.out.print(a[i]); 
            System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        //Call goldbach method on array a
        goldbach(a);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently seem to be iterating through the array of primes for each prime looking for one that sums to your target. That's not necessary; you just need to check whether the difference is a prime:

```
int[] primes;
int target;

for (int i = 2; i < target / 2; i++) {
    if (primes[i] != 0 && primes[target - i] != 0)
        ... 
}
```

Beyond that I can't see a lot of obvious optimisation but there may well be some numerical analysis that allows you to target likely primes first.